# spring field service required a bean of type

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm working on Spring over Hibernate project an i'm only in the beginning. I'm trying to have a SpringBootApplication which writes to MySql some Location objects. But every time i'm faceing some error. I did everything from my end refer everything still can't resolve it. Please help me out.
**This is my error**

---

```
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field service in com.project.abhishek.location.controller.LocationController 
required a bean of type'com.project.abhishek.location.service.LocationService' that could not be 
found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type'com.project.abhishek.location.service.LocationService' in your configuration.
```

**Application class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"com.project.abhishek.location.controller"})
@EntityScan(value ="com.project.abhishek.location.entity")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.project.abhishek.location.repos"})

public class StudentApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(StudentApplication.class, args);
}}
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class LocationController {

@Autowired
private LocationService service;

@RequestMapping("/saveLoc")
public String saveLocation(@ModelAttribute("location") Location location, ModelMap modelMap) {
    Location locationSaved = getService().saveLocation(location);

    String msg = "Location save with id:" +locationSaved.getId();
    modelMap.addAttribute("msg", msg);
    return "createLocation";
}

public LocationService getService() {
    return service;
}

public void setService(LocationService service) {
    this.service = service;
}
```

**Service Class**

```
@Service
public class LocationServiceImpl implements LocationService {

@Autowired
private LocationRepos locationRepos;

@Override
public Location saveLocation(Location location) {

    return locationRepos.save(location);
}

@Override
public Location updateLocation(Location location) {
    return locationRepos.save(location);
}

@Override
public void deleteLocation(Location location) {
    locationRepos.delete(location);
}

@Override
public Location getLocation(int id) {
    Optional<Location> optional = locationRepos.findById(id);
    Location location = optional.get();
    return location;
}

@Override
public List<Location> getAllLocation() {
    return locationRepos.findAll();
}

public LocationRepos getLocationRepos() {
    return locationRepos;
}

public void setLocationRepos(LocationRepos locationRepos) {
    this.locationRepos = locationRepos;
}
```

}

**Entity**

```
@Entity
public class Location {

@Id
private int id;
private String code;
private String name;
private String type;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getCode() {
    return code;
}

public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Location [id=" + id + ", code=" + code + ", name=" + name + ", type=" + type + "]";
}
```

**My packages structure are**

```
com.project.abhishek.location---application classs  
com.project.abhishek.location.controller---controller class  
com.project.abhishek.location.entity---entity class  
com.project.abhishek.location.repos---repository class  
com.project.abhishek.location.service---service class
```

Comment: Put your `@Service` annotation on `LocationService` interface and annotate implementation with `@Component`

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestion but getting same error.

Comment: Ok, then probably try to include `com.project.abhishek.location.service` in `@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"com.project.abhishek.location.controller"})`

Comment: thanks bro it worked, But may i know the reason why it was not working earlier as my service package is under application package. And for every service do i have to include it in @component scan everytime is there any other way.

Comment: I've added the answer with some explanations below.

Answer (score 0):

Just include `com.project.abhishek.location.service` in your `@ComponentScan` or simply delete `@ComponentScan`(this way it will scan spring boot application package `com.project.abhishek.location` and all packages below it).

By defining `@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"com.project.abhishek.location.controller"})` you overrode default component scan path `com.project.abhishek.location` and told spring to only scan `com.project.abhishek.location.controller` and packages below it, so it didn't scan `com.project.abhishek.location.service`.

Check this https://dzone.com/articles/spring-spring-boot-and-component-scan for more details on defining `@ComponentScan`. This is similar to your situation:

> However, let’s say one of the components is defined in package
> com.in28minutes.springboot.somethingelse
>
> In this case, you would need to add the new package into Component
> Scan.
>
> You have two options:
>
> Define @ComponentScan(“com.in28minutes.springboot”)  This would scan
> the entire parent tree of com.in28minutes.springboot.
>
> Or define two
> specific Component Scans by using an array.
> @ComponentScan({“com.in28minutes.springboot.basics.springbootin10steps”,”com.in28minutes.springboot.somethingelse”})

Comment: but if i'm not defining my controller package in @ComponentScan my mapping with dispatcherServlet was not done and i was getting "Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback."

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is required in Spring Boot, it's already there, `@SpringBootApplication` is sufficient.

Just make below changes and you will be good to go.

**Main Application Class:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class StudentApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(StudentApplication.class, args);
}}
```

**Controller Class:**  `@Autowired` is sufficient load your dependency, don't need to set, just see change you need to make in `@Service` notation where you need to name the interface name so dependency name can be `locationService` when you auto wired.

```
@RestController
public class LocationController {

@Autowired
private LocationService service;

@RequestMapping("/saveLoc")
public String saveLocation(@ModelAttribute("location") Location location, ModelMap modelMap) {
    Location locationSaved = getService().saveLocation(location);

    String msg = "Location save with id:" +locationSaved.getId();
    modelMap.addAttribute("msg", msg);
    return "createLocation";
}
```

**Change in Service Class:**

```
@Service("locationService)
public class LocationServiceImpl implements LocationService {
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but if i do so i'm getting same error. As told by Sergei Sirik if i include my service class package in @ComponentScan my problem is resolved. But just want to know suppose my application package is com.abc and service package com.abc.service then application class must scan this. Why explicitly i have to defined them in ComponentScan.